# Can I use adb.exe to find a description of a phone?

Tags: android, adb

If I call the command "adb.exe devices" I get a list of devices with a unique ID for each. These IDs are perfect for programming but not very human readable. Is there any way I can link one of these IDs to a (not necessarily unique) description of the phone? For example, if I have a device with an ID 1234567890abcdef is there any way I can figure that in real life it is a Motorola Droid X?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Android there is a `Model number` entry in settings that shows phone name.

There is a way to quickly see this via command line:

```
adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "product"
```

---

This is what's shown for ***Samsung Galaxy S 4G***:

```
ro.product.model=SGH-T959V
ro.product.brand=TMOUS
ro.product.name=SGH-T959V
ro.product.device=SGH-T959V
ro.product.board=SGH-T959V
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=Samsung
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=SGH-T959V
```

---

On a HTC Desire, the output looks like this:

```
ro.product.model=HTC Desire
ro.product.brand=htc_wwe
ro.product.name=htc_bravo
ro.product.device=bravo
ro.product.board=bravo
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=HTC
ro.product.locale.language=hdpi
ro.product.locale.region=
```

---

You can refine your query to show only one line:

```
adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "ro.product.device"
```

or

```
adb shell cat /system/build.prop | grep "ro.product.model"
```

Comment: On HTC devices, you'll probably want to look for the model i.e. ro.product.model=HTC Desire as device is used for their codenames (ro.product.device=bravo).

Comment: I've just edited answer to mention the `model` and then saw your comment :)

Comment: @David Caunt, Could you please edit my answer and add your HTC output results? So others can see the difference between `model` and `device`.

Comment: Is this a property that I can count on to be there, or is it up to the device manufacturer to decide whether or not to add it? I've checked on my Motorola Droid X and it is present.

Comment: I've updated the post - I think different manufacturers do different things as these values aren't required to conform to any standard.

Comment: As far as I know these properties are present in all emulators and real devices. I can't guarantee they are always present or point to some documentation that states this. My guess is those variables are part of the build process, and are required. I haven't checked this myself, though.

Comment: I've checked my other devices and they all have the value populated. Should be close enough for what I want to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With newer devices, you can run

`adb devices -l`

This will list some devices in a more human readable form

Example:

```
04d9a601ce516d53 device usb:1A134500 product:occam model:Nexus_4 device:mako
015d4b3406280a07 device usb:1A134700 product:nakasi model:Nexus_7 device:grouper
01466E620900F005 device usb:1A134600 product:mysid model:Galaxy_Nexus device:toro
```

Comment: How do you define "most recent versions of Android"?

Comment: I guess at this point, it's going to be most versions of Android. I believe the cutoff is Android 4.2 and upwards.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `adb shell cat /system/build.prop` is wonderful, but also as @Matt said, it sometimes differs because of different manufacture.

IMHO, the most reliable approach is the built-in command: `adb shell getprop`

======================================================================

Here is a comparison for an exception (Genymotion emulator):

By `adb shell cat /system/build.prop` you'll get

```
ro.product.brand=generic
ro.product.name=vbox86p
ro.product.device=vbox86p
ro.product.board=
ro.product.cpu.abi=x86
ro.product.manufacturer=Genymotion
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=US
```

So there is no model value :(

By `adb shell getprop` you'll get

```
[ro.product.manufacturer]: [Genymotion]
[ro.product.model]: [Nexus422ForAutomation]
[ro.product.name]: [vbox86p]
```

Here you get the model name: Nexus422ForAutomation :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no reliable way to do this since each manufacturer tweaks their build properties

If you type "adb help" into the command line you can see a list of the adb commands and a description for each.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script (on MacOS):

```
 #!/bin/bash

devices=`adb devices | grep "device" | grep -v "List of" | cut -d " " -f 1`

for device in $devices
do
    manufacturer=`adb -s $device shell getprop ro.product.manufacturer | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\$//'`
    model=`adb -s $device shell getprop ro.product.model | sed -e 's/[[:space:]]*\$//'`
    echo "$device: $manufacturer $model"
done
```

It produces e.g. the following output:

```
T076000UWX: motorola XT1053 
C4F12070E5A068E: samsung GT-P7510
4df1ff977b919f91: samsung GT-N7100 
4258393032523638324D: Sony Ericsson LT18i
```