# Android model number mismatch between Settings menu and Build.MODEL

Tags: android, api, model, adb

I've tested several Android handsets and found that on some specific devices, the model number presented in "Settings->About->(Phone identity)->Model number" is different from the model number retrieved using [Build.MODEL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL). I'm looking to find out how I can retrieve the model number presented via the Settings menu programmatically.

I've seen this issue on a couple of devices:

1. Actual Device is HTC Inspire 4G

   - Model number from Settings menu: HTC Inspire<sup>TM</sup> 4G
   - Model number from Build API:  Desire HD
2. Actual Device is Motorola Droid Razr Maxx HD

   - Model number from Settings menu: DROID RAZR MAXX HD
   - Model number from Build API: DROID RAZR HD

I've tried [inspecting the build.prop file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377444/can-i-use-adb-exe-to-find-a-description-of-a-phone/6377603#6377603) and did not find the model number found via the Settings menu. Your thoughts and ideas on retrieving the Settings menu value via the Android API or otherwise are appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `Build.PRODUCT` any better?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but Build.PRODUCT outputs 'htc_ace' for the Inspire and 'XT926_verizon' for the Razr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devices you mention are not vanilla-Android devices; they include some manufacturer customisation. The Motorola version is much closer to vanilla Android than the HTC version, but even so...

The exact information displayed in the Settings menu is one of the things that manufacturers *may* customise whenever they package their version of Android for inclusion on a particular device. There is unlikely to be any portable, reliable way of getting this information.

Comment: Any ideas on how to get it off of these particular devices (ignoring portability or reliability)?  I find it hard to believe that they would hardcode this into the binary.

Comment: I was never able to come up with a resolution specific to the devices in question.  Appreciate your insight here. Thanks!