# How to get OS version and Device Name of an Android device connected via USB with C#.net (VS2010/4.0+)?

Tags: c#, android, usb, windows, device

I want to build a windows application in C#.net which should identify the installed Adroid OS version (e.g. 4.0) and user friendly Device Name (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3, Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 etc.) when you connect an Android device to your computer via USB.

I tried with the `System.Management` class to identify the connected USB devices on my machine, however, the problems I had were:

I just have 3 USB ports and connected the Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9 on one of the USB ports and tried to get the list of USB devices using `USBhub WMI class` and I got around 6-7 results in the list including the Samsung device. So, the issues here are:

1. Why did I get 6-7 results when querying USBHub? Am I doing anything wrong here?
2. How can I filter my records to list only those USB ports which has an external device connected to it not 6-7 results?
3. I could not find the correct/user friendly Device Name I was expecting (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9) and no way to get the Android version OS. I tried 'Caption' and 'Description' properties, but they have very generic information such as just 'Samsung'. How can I get the user friendly device name and the installed Android OS version on the device.

Comment: I’d suggest using the Android SDK and just running an adb-process to find out all the information you need.

Comment: For example `adb.exe shell getprop ro.product.model` should give you the product name, `adb.exe shell getprop ro.build.version.release` the version number.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I could get the correct OS version by the version.release command. However, for the device name, it shows GT-P730 for a Samsung Galaxy Tab 8.9. Can I get this name by any command?

Comment: You can run just `adb.exe shell getprop` to get all available properties, maybe there is some other property which you can check but it will probably not work for all devices.

Comment: Thank you 'poke'! The command really helped to check various device info. However, it seems that the manufacturer sets these properties and Samsung seems one of those who just put a 'product-code' such as GT-P730 rather than the actual 'product-name' such as Samsung Galaxy Tab. I also found another article on StackOver flow:[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377444/can-i-use-adb-exe-to-find-a-description-of-a-phone [/link] which also explains the same thing for HTC. I think the best I could go for was the android OS version, manufacturer name and the model.Neverthless, thank you again.

Comment: I summarized my comments into an answer so you can accept that if it (somewhat) solves the problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) from the Android SDK to query properties from the connected devices. You can simply launch the `adb.exe` process from within .NET and use the results.

For example `adb.exe shell getprop ro.product.model` will give you the model name, and `adb.exe shell getprop ro.build.version.release` will give you the Android version number. To get a complete list of all available properties for a given device, you can also just run `adb.exe shell getprop`.

Note that the property names are not really standardized and manufacturers are not required to put in valuable names. It’s common that the product model contains the device’s code name or a product identifier that is not commonly used to identify the product among consumers.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to make changes into the device setting

1> At your android, go to settings -> applications -> development

2> Check USB Debugging

3> Make sure your device driver is already installed.

Android version 4.2 and above comes with security which wont allow you to fire the ADB commands without making changes in the settings.

Regards,
Aryan